# What does an exclamation mark after a variable definition mean in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, variables

I'm trying to learn TypeScript by going through some code in an application and I keep seeing variable! when defining a varialbe. For example:

```
protected _db!: CheckpointDB
```

Answer (score 0):

It has a value, so it can not be `null` or `undefined`.

Also called: "The non-null assertion operator"

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this?  Even without `!`, a non-optional class field must have a value and cannot be `null` or `undefined` (unless the field type includes `null` or `undefined` in its domain).